# Trigger to update field from a table when another table field is updated

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables one called t_engineer and one called t_lockers

When I update the locker_id in the table t_locker, the t_engineer table already has data in the locker_id field on that table, so I want to override this data with the new data that is put in the t_lockers tables.

This is what I have so far:

```
 CREATE or REPLACE 
TRIGGER IDT_Engineer_ID
AFTER UPDATE OF locker_id ON t_lockers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
update t_engineer.locker_id
set t_engineer.locker_id = t_lockers.locker_id
where t_engineer.locker_id = t_engineer.locker_id
END;
```

thanks

Tables are: 
[image]

[image]

and the schema is:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE "3PLData"
DATAFILE '3PLData.dbf' 
SIZE 5G
REUSE
AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 5G MAXSIZE 10G;

CREATE USER "3PL_SCHEMA" IDENTIFIED BY "7BK8-vE769J.7azQ"
DEFAULT TABLESPACE "3PLData"
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP";

GRANT "DBA" TO "3PL_SCHEMA" ;
GRANT "CONNECT" TO "3PL_SCHEMA" ;
GRANT "RESOURCE" TO "3PL_SCHEMA" ;
ALTER USER "3PL_SCHEMA" DEFAULT ROLE "DBA","CONNECT","RESOURCE";
```

Hope this provides you with enough info to see what the issue is...

Comment: Do provide schema details for questions of this type.

Also, provide an example of before and after value for tables in question. This will help in closing the question with less iterations.

Comment: I have edited the question above maybe this will help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IDT_Engineer_ID
AFTER INSERT ON t_lockers FOR EACH ROW
begin
    insert into t_engineer (locker_id) values (:NEW.locker_id);
end;
```

Comment: that did work thank you, however it lead me on to realise that this isn't the trigger I want :( I need one that will update the locker_id field in the t_engineer table when a new row of data is inserted into the t_lockers table. I assume I would also need to include in the trigger somewhere that the engineer_id in both tables would need to be equal. if you can help me out here it would be much appreciated!!

Comment: I have this so far but it doesn't work: create or replace TRIGGER IDT_Engineer_ID
AFTER INSERT
  ON t_lockers
  FOR EACH ROW
begin
    update t_engineer set locker_id = :NEW.locker_id
    where t_engineer.locker_id = :OLD.locker_id;
end;

Comment: thank you - I get this error - Error report:
ORA-04073: column list not valid for this trigger type
04073. 00000 -  "column list not valid for this trigger type"
*Cause:    A column list was specified for a non-update trigger type.
*Action:   Remove the column list.

Comment: try it again, if it didnt work, please write your columns of t_engineer and t_lockers tables, but this should work

Comment: tried it again and still didn't work,... I have updated the main question with more info...

Answer (score 0):

There is a flaw in table structure.

What is the relationship between engineer & locker?
Is it One to Many, Many to Many?

**In any case, you do not need to have engineer_id and locker_id in both the tables.**

Either have engineer_id and locker_id in t_locker and have only engineer_id in t_engineer

or

have locker_id in t_locker and engineer_id and locker_id in t_engineer